# Unification algorithm over a racket function?

Tags: types, functional-programming, scheme, racket

In my programming languages course we are reviewing unification algorithm by hand. The TA can't solve some examples of how to apply the unification algorithm to the `nmap` function in Racket. Could anybody explain to me how to apply the unification algorithm to any function in Racket? As an example, could anybody help me to apply the unification algorithm to this function:

```
 (define nmap
  (lambda(f l)
   (cond [(nempty? l) nempty]
         [(ncons? l)
          (ncons (f (nfirst l))
                 (nmap f (nrest l)))])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unification usually refers to a technique for solving a set of simultaneous equations using pattern-matching and variable replacement. It's often used in type-checking, to infer types for expressions. With that said, it's unclear to me exactly how you want to use unification on this piece of code. Are you thinking of a Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm? Or perhaps you're thinking of an entirely different meaning of the term.